# Why Context Switch time is different for different Linux OS but on same hardware?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel

I have calculated process context switch time and thread context switch time  both in Debian-8 and Ubuntu-14.04 ,same kernel version - 3.16.25 for both OS.

I have used following code -  [process context switch time](https://github.com/tsuna/contextswitch/blob/master/timectxsw.c) and    [thread_context_switch_time](https://github.com/tsuna/contextswitch/blob/master/timetctxsw.c)

I have tested on my Core-i7 (3.40GHz) system.

In Ubuntu, I got 1600/1300ns for process context switch time / thread context switch time.

In Debian 8, I got 980/980ns for process context switch time / thread context switch time.

Can anyone help me to clear my doubts -

1. Why debian OS takes less time for context switching although Ubuntu is based on Debian kernel.
2. Why different context switch time for different OS , but on Same hardware ?
3. In Ubuntu, process context switch time is higher than thread context switch time which is expected , but in Debian both are same. Why?

Comment: Just because it's the same upstream version, doesn't mean it's the same package version. My first guess is that Ubuntu backported more Spectre/Meltdown patches. That's a really old kernel version.

Comment: Also, I can't find 3.16.25 in either Debian or Ubuntu package archives.

Comment: I have tested with 3.18 kernel also. Different context switch time there also.

Comment: What is relationship among packages available in kernel module with context switch time ? Are there any indirect cost ?